# Change Logo image file after user login

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I want to change the content of a specific article by the time user login.
  So I create a plugin and put my code inside onUserLogin(), the problem is how do I get the content of this specific article? and if I change the content of the module, will use see the effect immediately?  An example cold would be much appreciated. Thanks is advance.

Best Regards
Scott

Comment: I think more information would be useful.  Do you want to permanently change the content of a single article every time a user logs in?  Or, perhaps you want to just adjust the content of one of more articles while the user is logged in?  You also mention a module, what role would this have?  I'd be happy to provide details and possible solutions if you can provide more specific information.

Comment: The title and question do not match. Do you want to change the logo of your site or text on a page once the user logs in?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a block of content or a logo, you can place the two different sets in modules, and embed BOTH of them in the page (using loadposition or the Modules button under the article editor in later versions of Joomla 3.x), but set one to Registered User and the other to Guest. Then go into the User Manager to the options and set the public group to Guest instead of Public.

Then the Guest module will only appear to those logged out, and the Registered User module will appear to those logged in.

The other option is to just use a plugin like this Content Filter (free and paid versions)

http://www.function90.com/products/content-filter.html